# SQL : how to calculate an average from a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've been using SQL for about a week at my first full time job, and I'm trying to calculate some statistics from a query where I've combined columns from separate tables.

Specifically, I'm trying to calculate an average from a combined table, where I have applied filters (or constraints? I'm not clear on the SQL lingo).

From doing [research on Google](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_avg.asp), I learned how to calculate an average:

```
SELECT AVG(column_name) 
FROM table_name
```

The problem I'm having is that this only seems to work with existing tables in the database, not with new queries I have created.

A simplified version of my code is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    Animal_Facts.Animal_Name, Animal_Facts.Prev_Reg_Amount, 
    Names.Given_Name, Animal_Class.Class_Description
FROM 
    Names
INNER JOIN
    Animal_Facts ON Names.Name_Key = Animal_Facts.Name_Key
INNER JOIN 
    Animal_Class ON Animal_Facts.Class_Key = Animal_Class.Class_Key
```

This query creates combines four columns from three tables, where `Class_Description` describes whether the animal is desexed, microchipped, owned by a pensioner etc, and Pre_Reg_Amount is the registration fee paid.

I want to find the average fee paid by pensioners, so I included the following line of code to filter the table:

```
AND Animal_Class.Class_Description LIKE ('%pensioner%')
```

And then to calculate the average I add:

```
SELECT AVG(Animal_Facts.Prev_Reg_Amount) from Animal_Facts
```

So my total code is:

```
SELECT 
    Animal_Facts.Animal_Name, Animal_Facts.Prev_Reg_Amount, 
    Names.Given_Name, Animal_Class.Class_Description
FROM 
    Names
INNER JOIN
    Animal_Facts ON Names.Name_Key = Animal_Facts.Name_Key
INNER JOIN
    Animal_Class ON Animal_Facts.Class_Key = Animal_Class.Class_Key
                 AND Animal_Class.Class_Description LIKE ('%pensioner%')

SELECT AVG(Animal_Facts.Prev_Reg_Amount) 
FROM Animal_Facts
```

Now the problem is, after checking this calculation in Excel, I'm not actually getting the average of the pensioner data, but the average of all the data. Is there a way to calculate averages (and other statistics) directly from my created table in SQL?

**Note:** I am able to calculate all these statistics by exporting the data to Excel, but it is much more time consuming. I'd much rather learn how to do this within SQL.

Comment: Welcome to the world of using SQL. The grass is very green here.

Comment: @mendosi - Thanks mate!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG(af.Prev_Reg_Amount)
FROM
    Animal_Facts af
    INNER JOIN Animal_Class ac
    ON af.Class_Key = ac.Class_Key
    AND Class_Description LIKE ('%pensioner%')
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that definitely got me the number I needed, and much faster than using excel.

Comment: Is there a way to build a table first, and then calculate statistics (in an Excel kind of manner I guess), or is this the best way to go about calculating averages?

Comment: @BJJBA sure you can build a table but if you want to do grouping and things at the same time of producing the table you will need to use a few different techniques.  Check out Window Functions AVG() OVER (), WITH CUBE, GROUPING SETS.  Excel is a front end tool.  It too dosen't create statistics at the same time as a table but rather it uses a dataset to create statistics from.  SQL query is like creating a dataset then you just add the functions you want on top.  So if you Want AVG() and SUM() of the above simply create another calculated column after SELECT AVG(), SUM().....